# Is it possible to shift more than 1 bit per cycle in verilog?

Tags: verilog, cycle, shift

I am not sure whether more than 1 cycle is needed, and if I will need to account for a shift taking more than 1 cycle to complete. And if it is possible to shift more than 1 bit at a time, does shifting 1 bit take he same amount of delay/gate time as shifting multiple bits?

Answer (score 1):

If you mean a combinational shift, then a fixed shift takes no logic at all: it is merely some change in the wiring. If you want a variable shift, then you can use these Verilog operators: `<<` (logical shift left), `>>` (logical shift right) or `>>>` (arithmetic shift right). Your synthesiser should synthesise a combinational circuit for these operators. The size and hence the delay though this will depend on the maximum shift required and the length of the word to be shifted. Whether that delay is more than one clock cycle depends on the frequency of your clock. Unless you have a very fast clock or a very long maximum shift, the delay will probably be easily less than a clock cycle.

Here is a combinational left-shifter in Verilog:

```
module ones_shift #(log2_width=2) (input [(2**log2_width)-1:0] A,  input [log2_width:0] SHIFT, output [(2**log2_width)-1:0] As);

  assign As = A << SHIFT;

endmodule
```

http://www.edaplayground.com/x/24P8

The shifter shifts the `A` input by the number of places represented by the `SHIFT` input, to give the `As` output.

If you mean a shift register (is a sequential circuit), then you'll get one shift per clock cycle.

Here is a shift register in Verilog:

```
module SHIFT_REG #(SIZE = 16) (input LOAD, SHIFT, CLOCK, RESET, [SIZE-1:0] A, output reg [SIZE-1:0] As);

  always @(posedge CLOCK or posedge RESET)
    if (RESET)
      As <= {SIZE{1'b0}};
    else
      if (LOAD)
        As <= A;
      else
        if (SHIFT)
          As <= {As[SIZE-2:0],1'b0};

endmodule
```

http://www.edaplayground.com/x/2bAW

If the `LOAD` input is high, the `A` input is loaded into the shift register. If the `SHIFT` input is high, then the register shifts to the left (one bit per `CLOCK` cycle). The `As` output is the parallel output from the shift register. The `RESET` input is active-high.

Comment: Say I was to do a left shift of 5 (<< 5) on a register. Would this take 5 cycles or 1 cycle? Would the synthesizer treat it as a shift register or would it do some trick that would make it only take 1 cycle?

Comment: @Brian Crafton The synthesiser will not make such a decision; you have to. When you design with an HDL, you are designing at a higher level of abstraction, but not that high. I could give examples of both a combinational shift and a shift register in Verilog, but now.

Comment: @Brian Crafton I have added some examples. If that does not help, perhaps you could supply some more detail about your question. What are you shifting? Why?